# Eclipse Helios crashes on SuSE

Tags: linux, eclipse, java

It crashes, saying:

```
/usr/lib64/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so: undefined symbol: g_proxy_resolver_get_type
```

My java is:

```
java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.6.2) (suse-0.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Eclipse ini:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /usr/local/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/local/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810/eclipse_1309.so
-startup /usr/local/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-exitdata 558004
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /usr/local/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
```

Has anyone experienced similar problem?

Best,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try this (where ever startup.jar is in eclipse):

```
java -jar /usr/lib/eclipse/startup.jar
```

Comment: the startup.jar file? There is no such file in Helios. I've tried however : java -jar /usr/local/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar but it doesn't help